# React version 1.2.5 not getting install

Tags: javascript, reactjs

although I am good in react but when I was tiring to install react version 1.2.5, I was getting this error again and again for running

```
npm i -g create-react-app@1.2.5
```

**Output**

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` 
instead.
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for create-react-app@1.2.5.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sibri\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-14T07_21_55_731Z- 
debug-0.log
```

Anyone got any idea where I went wrong

Comment: You try to install create-react-app @1.2.5 not a react itself, the version 1.2.5 doesnt exists. Please have a look at versioning https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the returned error you should use `--location=global` instead of `-g` flag.